# How do I enable Vue.js development on Docker machine?

Tags: docker, vue.js

I run Dockerize Vue.js App with Nginx as in official documentation [[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example)

It is running very clear but how can I run **npm run serve** for hot reload?
Where should I put this command?

Comment: I don't think you can. The nginx config is not meant to detect the reloader

Comment: If it's using NGINX, then the app has been built and deployed in a production-like environment. It is not for development